# Using @extschema@ in PostgreSQL is a syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a SQL vault from a [GitHub](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/rls-examples/blob/master/signed-vault/signed_vault--1.0.sql) project with the following statement:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA @extschema@ TO PUBLIC;
```

which results in the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 101: GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA @extschema@ TO PUBLIC;
```

As far as I can see `@extschema@` is not foreign to PostgreSQL, but I don't know how to fix it. Any hints are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@extschema@` only in the SQL script that creates an extension, where PostgreSQL replace that placeholder with the extension schema before executing the script.

In  other contexts that will cause an error.